# Getting node no longer exist in php and xml with memcache

Tags: php, xml, memcached

I have the following code that caches the xml output. The problem is after it caches the xml object into memcache and then I access the xml object in memcache I get the error:

"Warning: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Node no longer exists in ..."

```
$cachekey = md5($url);

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$data = $memcache->get($cachekey);

if($data === FALSE)
{

$data = simplexml_load_file($url);

$memcache->set($cachekey,$data,FALSE,900) or die ("Failed to create cache set");

}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7647729/1232478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work, instead of loading the xml file from the url I downloaded it into a string, then loaded the xml from string:

```
$cachekey = md5($url);

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$data = $memcache->get($cachekey);

if($data === FALSE)
{

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$memcache->set($cachekey,$data,FALSE,900) or die ("Failed to create cache set");

}

$xmldata = simplexml_load_string($data);
```